# Compare heap dump (HPROF) files

Tags: android, memory-leaks, dump, eclipse-memory-analyzer

Is it possible to compare two HPROF files? How?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

From what I found you can compare only histograms of object. For this go to "Histogram" view, then click "Compare to another Heap Dump" and select another hprof file.

Here is screenshot:[image]

Comment: get to that myself too... also explained here: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+blogspot%2FhsDu+%28Android+Developers+Blog%29

Comment: In addition I saw a blog post that mentioned "Recent versions of MAT have extended differencing capabilities beyond the class histogram by introducing the compare basket. Explore the "Comparing Objects" topic in MAT's Help Contents for more information."