# Java: Memory Analyzer Tool (MAT) usage: comparing two heapdump

Tags: java, profiling

I am using Eclipse + MAT plugin. I could see one .hprof file heap history, I take two snapshot of my Java application. I wish when I compare two heap dump, I could figure which objects instance increase a lot so that I could identify the potential of memory leak.

Could netbean do that?

Comment: Duplicate of the question that already has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6242089/1078886

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare heap dump (HPROF) files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241965/compare-heap-dump-hprof-files)

Answer (score 10):

## Instructions

1. Open both heap dumps in [MAT](https://www.eclipse.org/mat/downloads.php)
2. Open the histogram for the whichever heap dump demonstrates the anomalous behavior (usually the one with the higher memory or thread usage).

[image]

3. Compare it to another heap dump

[image]

4. Select the appropriate heap dump from the list

[image]

## Interpreting results

[image]

**Class Name:** The class that is instantiated in the application, taking up memory

**Objects:** The *count* of how many instances of the class are present *above or below* the other heap dump.

**Shallow Heap:** The number of bytes the given class is taking up in memory *above or below* the other heap dump.

## Tips

Since MAT sorts descending by default **I recommend** toggling the ordering of the *Objects* and *Shallow Heap* columns to see the top outliers for each in both directions.

Typically you should ignore the pure Java classes like Strings, Arrays, and Maps and focus on the classes that *your app* defines.

## Reference

[Comparing Objects Official Eclipse Help Doc](http://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.mat.ui.help%2Ftasks%2Fcomparingdata.html)

Answer (score 2):

Can be done. See [IBMs blog](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/kevgrig/entry/how_to_use_the_memory_analyzer_tool_mat_to_compare_heapdumps_and_system_dumps20?lang=en).

Basically you open both and then in the histogram there is an additional button (the most right one) to compare it.